# Enviromental variables into text file

Tags: batch-file

How do I write enviromental variables into text file with my name?
My code is like:

```
@echo off
cd c:\users\user\desktop\
set /p name = "Input filename: "
copy nul %name%.txt
set > %name%.txt
```

But it doesn't create any file.

Comment: What do you want to write in `%name%.txt` ?

Comment: If you want to send random environment variables in `%name%.txt` you can try: `echo %MY_VARIABLE% >> %name%.txt`.

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't created a file called `.txt`? If you look into that file, you may find that there is a line `name =yourname` because `set` is sensitive to spaces on *both* sides of the `=`. Remove the space before `=`  otherwise you set a variable called `name[space]`

Comment: @Magoo, thanks a lot! That worked out since i removed spaces around `=`

Comment: Since you tagged it with `PowerShell` as well: `$env:myvariableName | Set-Content $filePath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with:

```
set /p name = "Input filename: "
```

The space immediately following the `name` will actually create a variable name called `name<space>`, which you will be able to see if you execute `set nam` to show all variables starting with that value.

See the following transcript for proof:

```
C:\pax> set /p x = ?
?with-space

C:\pax> set /p x=?
?no-space

C:\pax> set x
x=no-space
x =with-space
```

That transcript also shows how to *fix* it, simply change your line to remove the spaces:

```
set /p name="Input filename: "
```